# How can I reference mounted secrets from Secret Manager in a python Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mount, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to reference a series of APIs and would like peace of mind for key security, so I am storing keys in Secret Manager. However, the documentation doesn't specify the best method of connecting to a mounted path within the Cloud Function.

[image]

Suppose my secret was named key6 and has a mount path of /api/secret/key6 - How would I call this in python?

I attempted this method: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-python
However, given that this didn't use the mounted path, I wanted to see if there was a better implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process to read the secret is via standard file operations in Python. So if the path is `/api/secret/key6` , then you could do something like:

```
secret_location = '/api/secret/key6'

with open(secret_location) as f:
    YOUR_SECRET = f.readlines()[0]
```

Just ensure that you have given the service account running your Cloud Functions, the necessary permissions to access the Secrets.